# PLEASE HELP! Contract deployment to Money.sol remixetheriumcompiler- contract interaction start . IDK crypto I need to recover my funds

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, scam

I recently had a loss in my family and was trying to raise some extra funds quickly. I was given this instruction, and when I called to withdrawal I realized it was trying to take the funds from my address instead of deposit. The money is still in the contract address It went to, and I need to get it back to my Metamask account. Here's the transaction id- 0xba6ec8dc98af0f1acd213d1bbf351e43788dda090a1136ad9e701ec638a3563f Here's my eth address 0x273567a993B6cB7EA0A0296Ae54E4a876cD61089 and the address it was sent to  0xE1eFeFc33c5AD296eFE7224600CE864343f1B6a3

**Here are the scammer instruction I followed**

IMPORTANT INFORMATION BELOW

Be sure to read the description to avoid any potential issues or misunderstandings.

Thanks to Ethereum's slow transaction processing times, high tx fees and Uniswap's smartcontract nature, frontrunning transactions is much much easier than in traditional orderbook-based markets. We can exploit this to our advantage. In this video I will teach you how to create a Uniswap trading bot that can easily make you $800+/day.

You can message me here if you need help (please keep it concise, I'm receiving many messages and have a hard time keeping up, chances are your question has already been addressed in the description):
`<shady telegram channel>`

1. Download MetaMask:

`<dubious download link>`

2. Access Remix:

`<odd looking remix copy>`

3. Click on the "contracts" folder and then create a "New File". Rename it as you like, i.e: "bot.sol"
   The file name has to end with ".sol" which is the Solidity language file extension.
4. Paste this code into Remix:

`<scam contract pastebin>`

5. Move to the "Solidity Compiler" tab, select version "0.6.6" and then "Compile" it.
   (If you have trouble compiling, try refreshing remix and recreating the "bot.sol" file.)
6. Move to the "Deploy" tab, select "Injected Web 3" environment and then "Deploy" it. After the transaction is confirmed, it's your own BOT now

Note: If you get the "This contract may be abstract" error when you deploy, you may need to select the right contract from the "CONTRACT" dropdown list above the "Deploy" button, the name should start with "UniswapFrontrunBot".

7. Deposit funds to your bot contract's address
8. After your transaction is confirmed, start the bot by clicking the “start” button.
9. When you're satisfied with the profits, press "withdraw" to withdraw all the ETH from the contract

Share your profits in the comments, like & subscribe for more Web 3.0 tutorials.

IMPORTANT
I got messages from people who didn't fund the contract with enough to cover gas fees and possible burn fees. The bot targets tokens with 10% burn fees or less. Nowadays most tokens come with 3-6% fees. If you fund the contract with 0.4 ETH or less and the bot targets a token with high burn fees, the contract may lose more on fees than it can generate in profits. I recommend funding the contract with at least 0.5 - 1 ETH to guarantee this will not happen.

PLEASE HELP!! Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: I'm in the same situation! Did you manage to WITHDRAW from the Contract's wallet and sent it back into your funding wallet? Also, I don't get the scam. How is he profiting from it. The ether is still all there in the Contract address. Is it slowly dwindling away to be almost imperceptable?

Comment: The contracts usually have a backdoor that can be exploited by the creator.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of scams such as this one. Remix also introduced a warning for every time you paste a code in the editor to prevent such scams. Unfortunately, the contract was designed in a way, where you can not withdraw your funds.

It is never a good idea to deploy a contract that someone else wrote, especially if you are not familiar with solidity. I would advise you to forget about the money and use this as a lesson to be more careful next time since there is no such thing as easy money.

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry this happened to you. People always advise you not to put your signature before reading a legal contract.

But deploying and calling a smart contract you can't read is the worse version of that. What I hate the most is that this same contract had been circulating for the last few years and every few months there is a post similar to this one.

It's not your fault, it's just that there are some really scammy bastards out there preying on people.